# AWS max upload limit issue

Tags: php, laravel, amazon-web-services, nginx, nginx-config

I have a laravel project uploaded to aws using elastic beanstalk. I'm facing issue with uploading files. The limitation was at first 2MB. I updated the php.ini and the nginx.conf. But the limitation changed to 20MB only. Not able to upload bigger files however in the configuration is set the limitation to 2G. I checked the nginx.conf file today and the configurations I added disappeared and that happened twice. Any idea why this happening?

[image: Nginx issue]

Comment: Are you sure, that you made changes in correct `php.ini` file?

Comment: Without knowing the exact setup of your AWS environment... hard to say. Maybe ask AWS support why your files are being changed?

Comment: @BadPiggie Yes I'm sure

Comment: @LarsStegelitz Thanks. I'll do that.

Answer (score 0):

For Nginx and PHP you have to set in two files:

php.ini

```
post_max_size = 2G
upload_max_filesize = 2G
```

In Nginx conf (like vhost apache)

```
upload_max_filesize = 2G
```

Example of one AWS Image (Bitnami - NGinx with WordPress)

The default php.ini files are set in "/opt/bitnami/php/etc/php.ini", you cna check the location using "phpinfo();".
In this file I need to change post_max_size and upload_max_filesize.

In NGinx, the settings is being set individual per project (website), then I need to go to "/opt/bitnami/apps/wordpress/conf/nginx-prefix.conf" and add the line
"upload_max_filesize = 2G". After that just need to restart php-fpm and nginx services using "sudo /opt/bitnami/ctlscript.sh restart".

Comment: @AhmedAbdeen What image in AWS you are using?

Sometimes the nginx conf gets overwrites in htdocs/conf folders. Its possible that upload_max_filesize  is set to 2G in global nginx file, and in your project (vhost) is another value, that is being overwrite.